# Laravel service container is it possible to bind to class AND all it's ancestors - like in Symfony

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ioc-container

I have base class like this:

```
class BaseAPI
{

    public function __construct(Client $client, CacheInterface $cache,  $apiBaseUri)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->apiBaseUri = $apiBaseUri;
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }
}
```

And then in provider:

```
class APIServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app
        ->when(BaseAPI::class)
        ->needs('$apiBaseUri')
        ->give(env('DEFAULT_API_URI',''));
    }
}
```

That is working. 
But when I'm making ancestor:

```
class GetLocations extends BaseAPI
{
     protected $apiMethodName = 'locations';
     protected $type = 'get';
}
```

I'm getting error. Of course I can manually write code for each of ancestors, but there is a lot's of them, so question is: is there any inheritance mechanism for binding?
Something like this:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parent_services.html

Comment: If it's possible in symfony it is possible in Laravel

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use interface for this?

```
class BaseAPI implements APIInterface
{
}

class APIServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app
        ->when(APIInterface::class)
        ->needs('$apiBaseUri')
        ->give(env('DEFAULT_API_URI',''));
    }
}
```